# Bootstrap stretching images with a fixed width

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, woocommerce

I am using bootstrap with woocommerce (using the JBST theme) and it's stretching images to 100% which is what I would want but unfortunately, it's making those images blurry, especially the thumbnails for woocommerce. The thumbnails have a fixed witdh and I want to keep them at their intended size. I went through the css and removed any reference to width:100% for images yet the thumbnails are still being stretched. Any ideas?

Comment: Are the images being given an explicit height and width in the HTML that's being generated on the page? It may not be CSS that is determining the size of the images. In your case, I doubt it is.

Comment: You need to show us the code you have, there's some bootstrap styles that you could apply for that, please improve your question.